# How to make a 'video lightbox' video 'breakout' of an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a master(parent) page index.html. I put an iframe in my master page, iframe width=535 height=1330. I put menu in master page & all page show in iframe. I have a video gallery page create by video lightBox. If i click on video, it's played fine but in side the iframe. If I make it full screen also it stay in side iframe.

So i want the video in iframe, that show in master page.

My Master page code

My video gallery page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index_videolb/videolightbox.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_videolb/overlay-minimal.css"/>

<script src="index_videolb/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="index_videolb/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <!-- End VideoLightBox.com HEAD section -->
```

```
<div class="videogallery">
```

Stream Video to Website by VideoLightBox.com v2.4

```
</div>

<script src="index_videolb/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="index_videolb/videolightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- End VideoLightBox.com BODY section --></td>
  </tr>
```

---

So please help me to give me any script or, any code to change, that can solved my problem.

Thank you

MAHS

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this following iframe code:

```
  <iframe src="page.html" width="535" height="1130">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </iframe>
```

For exp: You can embed it in page.html in your index.html